# Horizontal view does not scroll and breaks the spacing of the page elements

Tags: ios, ios5

When the emulator is in horizontal view, the button do not all fit in the screen, and what I would think is that the user needs to scroll.

But for some reason, there is no ability to scroll and the bottom button gets pushed up, making the screen looks broken.

Here is how that looks:

[image]

Is this typical? What is usually the solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: try to check/uncheck in your storyboard's file inspector "Use Autolayout", besides it seems you do not have a scrolview how do you expect it to scroll?

Comment: @SpaceDust I wasn't sure...I thought the system would just scroll without a scrollview :)

Comment: @SpaceDust By the way, under which screen in the inspector is the Use Autolayout checkbox?  Thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure if system will detect or create an auto scrolview, I always use a tableviewcontroller when I need a scrollview. I will provide an answer for you in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a tableviewcontroller instead of  a regular view controller. Go to your storyboard drag a Tableview controller to your storyboard screen and connect it to whatever it should look like something like this

[image]

Then just delete the Table View Cell if you do not need it

[image]

Then drag and drop a view from objects it should look like this

[image]

Then adjust view's height as you wish. And add whatever you want

[image]

**One important thing though when you choose viewcontroller's class you need to choose a UITableviewcontroller class**

**So just add a new objective -c file (inherit from tableviewcontroller)**